# How to use Gson to parse dynamic object into JSONObject

Tags: parsing, gson, json

Is there a way to use Gson to parse a JSON response like this into the model class below?

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "phone": "123456789",
    "config": {
        "dynamicKey1": "true",
        "dynamicKey2": "123"
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class User {
    int id;
    String phone;
    JSONObject config;
}
```

The keys in the `config` objects may or may not exist. 
After deserialization, I want to be able to query the config keys dynamically using something like `user.getConfig().optBoolean("dynamicKey1")`

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was to use `com.google.gson.JsonObject` instead of `org.json.JSONObject`. Using `JsonObject` from Gson, the deserialization worked perfectly, and accessing the dynamic keys looks like this:

```
user.getConfig().getAsJsonPrimitive("dynamicKey1").getAsBoolean()
```

Answer (score 0):

User Config:

```
public class User {

int id;
String phone;
Map<String, String> config;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Map<String, String> getConfig() {
    return config;
}
public void setConfig(Map<String, String> config) {
    this.config = config;
}

}
```

Main Class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input = "{\"id\": 123,\"phone\": \"123456789\",\"config\": {\"dynamicKey1\": \"true\",\"dynamicKey2\": \"123\"}}";

    Gson gsonInstance = null;

    gsonInstance = new GsonBuilder().create();

    User user = gsonInstance.fromJson(input, User.class);

    boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(user.getConfig().get("dynamicKey1"));
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

You can create a map of DynamicKeys in Config section this way and then convert to respective primitive types whenever required.

Hope it helps.